# ASP.net MVC Web API with Session/Cookie based auth from web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am building an ASP.net MVC Web App with Local Authentication. I want to add some Web API endpoints, not for external use, but purely for use by jQuery AJAX calls on my own pages. So I added a Web API controller.

In order to integrate the authentication, I can do something like this:

```
[Authorize]
public IQueryable<object> GetLabels(int ModuleId)
{
    return db.Labels.Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name, ModuleID = x.ModuleId }).Where(x => x.ModuleID == ModuleId );
}
```

This provides the desired behaviour. However, I encounter one problem: when accessing the API as a logged out user, it responds with the HTML response of the login page.

I would rather respond with a small JSON object giving an error or a 401 error. How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the Authorized attribute and do something like

```
if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "");
}
return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, yourobject);
```

and change the return type to HttpResponseMessage;

Comment: but if I change the response type to HttpResponseMessage, the response is not serializable to JSON apparently... hmmm...

Comment: @ian93 serialize it yourself then, something like JavaScriptSerializer or Newton.JsonSerializer